# Mysqli joined query very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, left-join

My website had nested queries that were storing results and ended up giving me problems as my code got larger.  I am trying to learn how to join tables and do subqueries so I can streamline my code.  This query returns the exact information I need, but my page load time went from 1 second to 9 seconds after adding this query.  Is there some way to speed this up, or is there something I'm missing in it that is making it take so long?

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
       p.product_name, 
       p.product_pic, 
       AVG(r.review_stars), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT r.review_id), 
       (SELECT c.price_price FROM prices as c WHERE c.price_product=p.product_id ORDER BY c.price_price ASC LIMIT 1), 
       (SELECT c.price_vendor FROM prices as c WHERE c.price_product=p.product_id ORDER BY c.price_price ASC LIMIT 1) as VID, 
       p.product_url, 
       p.product_clicks, 
       SUM(c.price_clicks), 
       COUNT(c.price_price), 
       c.price_affiliate, 
       (SELECT v.vendor_name FROM vendors as v WHERE v.vendor_id=VID LIMIT 1) 
FROM products as p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews as r ON p.product_id = r.review_product
LEFT OUTER JOIN prices as c ON c.price_product = p.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_clicks DESC
LIMIT 21
```

Comment: post the table structures

Comment: This is slow because you use a lot of subqueries that are dependent on the main query. They are the 3 sub queries to get prices.price_price, prices.price_vendor, vendors.vendor_name. You can speed up the query by getting other information first then join the result set with prices and vendors to get out those bits of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the query as the following to reduce the impact of subqueries:

```
SELECT

main_results.*,

(SELECT c.price_price FROM prices as c WHERE c.price_product=main_results.product_id ORDER BY c.price_price ASC LIMIT 1),
(SELECT c.price_vendor FROM prices as c WHERE c.price_product=main_results.product_id ORDER BY c.price_price ASC LIMIT 1) as VID,
(SELECT v.vendor_name FROM vendors as v WHERE v.vendor_id=VID LIMIT 1)

FROM

(

    SELECT p.product_id, 
           p.product_name, 
           p.product_pic, 
           AVG(r.review_stars), 
           COUNT(DISTINCT r.review_id),                 
           p.product_url, 
           p.product_clicks, 
           SUM(c.price_clicks), 
           COUNT(c.price_price), 
           c.price_affiliate               
    FROM products as p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews as r ON p.product_id = r.review_product
    LEFT OUTER JOIN prices as c ON c.price_product = p.product_id
    GROUP BY p.product_id
    ORDER BY p.product_clicks DESC
    LIMIT 21

) AS main_results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly make it even faster that vidaica's code.

products would need INDEX(product_clicks, product_id); then see if this gives you the ids needed:

SELECT product_id FROM products ORDER BY product_clicks DESC LIMIT 21;

The replace this line:

FROM products as p

with

FROM ( SELECT product_id FROM products ORDER BY product_clicks DESC LIMIT 21 ) as ids
JOIN products p ON p.product_id = ids.product_id

(There may be a few more tweaks needed, such as removing the outer LIMIT.)

The principle behind his suggestion is to whittle down the data to only 21 rows before doing the subqueries.  I carried that one step further by also avoiding the JOINs until there are only 21.  Furthermore, the INDEX I picked allows the scan to be done in the INDEX, rather than reaching into the table to find product_clicks.

See the EXPLAIN for "Using index".